# pandas как удалить строку, фрагмент которой содержит строку из другой таблицы

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Есть два датафрейма:

```
df_01 = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2"],
                      "B": ["1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3"],
                      "C": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]})
```

и

```
df_02 = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["1", "2"],
                      "B": ["1", "1"]})
```

Нужно из df_01 удалить те строки, где есть комбинация "A" и B" из df_02.

Т.е. на выходе должно быть:

```
    A   B   C
0   1   2   b
1   1   3   c
2   2   2   e
3   2   3   f
```

Я пробовал через query:

```
df_01.query('A != "df_02.A" & B != "df_02.B"')
```

Но не фильтруется.

Также пробовал через drop:

```
df_01 = df_01.drop(df_01[(df_01.A != df_02.A) & (df_01.B != df_02.B)].index)
```

Но `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

делаете простую конкатенацию и удаляете дубликаты по нужным колонкам:

```
res = pd.concat([df_01,df_02]).drop_duplicates(subset=["A", "B"], keep=False)
```

res:

```
   A  B  C
1  1  2  b
2  1  3  c
4  2  2  e
5  2  3  f
```

Comment: точно, можно же управлять дубликатами в keep. Спасибо!